# How to play a video in my app

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, ios-simulator

So I have been working on getting a small (> 1 MB) video to play in my app. I keep getting a 'SIGABRT' error when I step past the break point in my code. Being the newbie, I haven't found any insight into what I am doing wrong.

I am using Xcode 4.2.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the code instead of posting a screenshot.

Comment: Ya good point. I ended up turning of ARC and fixing the file type issue and that fixed everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re using the following code to get a URL for your movie:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WhatV1.mp4" ofType:@"mp4"]];
```

You’re specifying the `mp4` portion twice. Try changing that to `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WhatV1" ofType:@"mp4"];`.

Additionally, are you running this on a device or on the simulator? Video frameworks crashing on the simulator are par for the course. Try testing on an iOS device.

Comment: You are right. I am still learning. Now to try and get it into my real app.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the extension in your pathForResource parameter.